# Api platform documentation diferent examples for request and response - ApiProperty( example: iri)

Tags: api-platform.com, symfony6

I need to have one example of the request and one for the response in api platform docs.
If I put example in the ApiProperty it replaces both request and response

```
    #[
        ORM\ManyToOne,
        ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false, onDelete: 'CASCADE'),
        ApiProperty(example: '/api/v1/users/1'),
    ]
    private User $user;
```

How can I see user entity object in the response

```
{
  "user": {
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Smith",
    "email": "john.smith@example.com",
    "mobile_phone_number": "+49123456789"
  }
}
```

and IRI in the request example.

```
{
  "user": "/api/v1/users/1"
}
```